# Seeing changes made in connected folder using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am working on a project in ArcGIS Desktop and I have a connected folder.  In it are multiple files. If I change a file in the folder (add or delete) it seems that I need to close my project and then re-open it to see the changes in the folder.

Is there a way to by-pass this?

Answer (score 2):

Right click the folder > Click Refresh. This way you can see the changes without having to re-open the project.